# Input field full width on bootstrap 4.0.0 not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have some problem on `Bootstrap 4.0.0` for input field full width across the column `col-md-6`

Here is my code. I just try to fix full width !

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">

    <div class="socialMedia d-flex">
      <span><img src="https://i.imgur.com/tyO9m6X.png" alt=""></span>
      <span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="socialMedia d-flex">
      <span><img src="https://i.imgur.com/tyO9m6X.png" alt=""></span>
      <span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="socialMedia d-flex">
      <span><img src="https://i.imgur.com/tyO9m6X.png" alt=""></span>
      <span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="socialMedia d-flex">
      <span><img src="https://i.imgur.com/tyO9m6X.png" alt=""></span>
      <span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="socialMedia d-flex">
      <span><img src="https://i.imgur.com/tyO9m6X.png" alt=""></span>
      <span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="socialMedia d-flex">
      <span><img src="https://i.imgur.com/tyO9m6X.png" alt=""></span>
      <span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </span>

    </div>
    <div class="socialMedia d-flex">
      <span><img src="https://i.imgur.com/tyO9m6X.png" alt=""></span>
      <span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="socialMedia d-flex">
      <span><img src="https://i.imgur.com/tyO9m6X.png" alt=""></span>
      <span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the expected output ! If any markup suggestion for following output, please help me

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: The `span` tags around your `input` elements is causing the width to be shortened. Sebastian has the correct answer below for how the form should be set up with Bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you have two `span` elements inside each `col-6`. one of them should have a fixed size, and the other one (containing the input) should fill the rest of the space

Basically, I used `flex` to do that. `socialMedia` was used to make the parent element use the flex box model.

`kb-icon` was set to not grow or shrink, while `kb-input` was set to grow, meaning it will take up the rest of the space for each `col-6` item

I also changed the spans into divs since (at least with the input) you want the item to have a specific size that is not based on the content of the element. The same could have been achieved by adding `display: inline-block` or `display: block`.

```css
.socialMedia {
  display: flex;
  padding: 2px 0;
}

.kb-icon {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin: 0 5px;
  /* just to make the icon centered */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}


/* this item will act as a pseudo input element
   we do that because we can't put a button inside
   an actual input */

.kb-input {
  flex-grow: 1;
  /* I use flex to make the input as
  large as possible without setting sized myself */
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 5px;
  /* just to make it look better on small screens */
  border: 1px solid grey;
  /* imitate the input look */
}


/* this is used to create a focus effect on the fake input. if we use focus and not focus-within, nothing will happen. I use the same method bootstrap uses here */

.kb-input:focus-within {
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 123, 255, .25);
}

.kb-input input {
  /* remove the input style to make it "transparent" */
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  /* this is used to make sure it takes up the entire space */
  flex-grow: 1;
}


/* make sure input does not have style on focus */

.kb-input input:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}


/* make the button transparent */

button.kb-close {
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">

    <div class="socialMedia d-flex">
      <div class="kb-icon"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/tyO9m6X.png" alt=""></div>
      <div class="kb-input">
        <input type="text" class="form-control ">
        <button class="kb-close">
        <i class="material-icons">close</i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="socialMedia d-flex">
      <div class="kb-icon"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/tyO9m6X.png" alt=""></div>
      <div class="kb-input">
        <input type="text" class="form-control ">
        <button class="kb-close">
        <i class="material-icons">close</i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="socialMedia d-flex">
      <div class="kb-icon"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/tyO9m6X.png" alt=""></div>
      <div class="kb-input">
        <input type="text" class="form-control ">
        <button class="kb-close">
        <i class="material-icons">close</i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="socialMedia d-flex">
      <div class="kb-icon"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/tyO9m6X.png" alt=""></div>
      <div class="kb-input">
        <input type="text" class="form-control ">
        <button class="kb-close">
        <i class="material-icons">close</i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="socialMedia d-flex">
      <div class="kb-icon"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/tyO9m6X.png" alt=""></div>
      <div class="kb-input">
        <input type="text" class="form-control ">
        <button class="kb-close">
        <i class="material-icons">close</i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="socialMedia d-flex">
      <div class="kb-icon"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/tyO9m6X.png" alt=""></div>
      <div class="kb-input">
        <input type="text" class="form-control ">
        <button class="kb-close">
        <i class="material-icons">close</i>
        </button>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="socialMedia d-flex">
      <div class="kb-icon"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/tyO9m6X.png" alt=""></div>
      <div class="kb-input">
        <input type="text" class="form-control ">
        <button class="kb-close">
        <i class="material-icons">close</i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="socialMedia d-flex">
      <div class="kb-icon"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/tyO9m6X.png" alt=""></div>
      <div class="kb-input">
        <input type="text" class="form-control ">
        <button class="kb-close">
        <i class="material-icons">close</i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

I also added some comments in the `CSS` to explain why I did what I did to add the "clean input" button

basically, `.kb-input` is used as a pseudo input element (containing the actual input and a button). for more info, check the `css`.

If you want to remove the outline completely, don't apply the `focus-within` pseudo class, and make sure you set the following attributes on the element you want to disable it for:

```
outline: 0;
box-shadow: 0;
```

Comment: Could you help me to add close icon on right as like as screenshot

Comment: @Momin sure. added the button as well to my answer.

it makes things a bit more complicated but I tried to add some explanations on why I do what I do in the css :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot  @Thatkookooguy

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following, using a `.form-group`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="socialMedia form-group row">
      <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-1 col-form-label">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/tyO9m6X.png" alt="">
      </label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control ">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="socialMedia form-group row">
      <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-1 col-form-label">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/tyO9m6X.png" alt="">
      </label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control ">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="socialMedia form-group row">
      <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-1 col-form-label">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/tyO9m6X.png" alt="">
      </label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control ">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="socialMedia form-group row">
      <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-1 col-form-label">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/tyO9m6X.png" alt="">
      </label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control ">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="socialMedia form-group row">
      <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-1 col-form-label">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/tyO9m6X.png" alt="">
      </label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control ">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="socialMedia form-group row">
      <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-1 col-form-label">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/tyO9m6X.png" alt="">
      </label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control ">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="socialMedia form-group row">
      <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-1 col-form-label">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/tyO9m6X.png" alt="">
      </label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control ">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="socialMedia form-group row">
      <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-1 col-form-label">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/tyO9m6X.png" alt="">
      </label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control ">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center this, read about offsetting:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns

My proposition:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 offset-sm-3 offset-md-3 col-offset-3">

    <div class="socialMedia d-flex">
      <span><img src="https://i.imgur.com/tyO9m6X.png" alt=""></span>
      <span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control ">
                  </span>
    </div>
    <div class="socialMedia d-flex">
      <span><img src="https://i.imgur.com/tyO9m6X.png" alt=""></span>
      <span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                  </span>
    </div>
    <div class="socialMedia d-flex">
      <span><img src="https://i.imgur.com/tyO9m6X.png" alt=""></span>
      <span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                  </span>
    </div>
    <div class="socialMedia d-flex">
      <span><img src="https://i.imgur.com/tyO9m6X.png" alt=""></span>
      <span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                  </span>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <div class="socialMedia d-flex">
      <span><img src="https://i.imgur.com/tyO9m6X.png" alt=""></span>
      <span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                  </span>
    </div>
    <div class="socialMedia d-flex">
      <span><img src="https://i.imgur.com/tyO9m6X.png" alt=""></span>
      <span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                  </span>

    </div>
    <div class="socialMedia d-flex">
      <span><img src="https://i.imgur.com/tyO9m6X.png" alt=""></span>
      <span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                  </span>
    </div>
    <div class="socialMedia d-flex">
      <span><img src="https://i.imgur.com/tyO9m6X.png" alt=""></span>
      <span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                  </span>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```